# The email address is badly formatted. I don't know what's wrong with this can someone help me.

Tags: javascript, firebase

[Code is not working, I dont know what was the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW3Dy.png)

Comment: where is code?share it here?

Comment: you better please share the code here or as a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the email format is reliant on the element in the page with id = 'emailAddress'. Check that it is in the correct format.

Also, if it doesn't run, try changing the last line from:

```
}());
```

To:

```
})();
```